# Editing the output of a R Summary Function

Tags: r, shiny, summary

The output of my R summary function is generating tabular data in which some of the cells have values like :

"Max. 12312"
"Min. 123123"
"Mean ....."

etc.

I would like to remove the part containing "Max." , "Min." etc as the labeling of this data is already taken care of in the first column of the table.

So I wrote a for loop (yes I know for loops to be avoided - but before writing efficient code, I am trying to get the algorithm right here )

```
columnNames<-colnames(sum_dframe)
  for(i in 1:length(columnNames))
  {
    varColData<-sum_dframe[,i]

    if(grepl("Alpha-Numeric",sug_dtype[i],fixed = TRUE) !=TRUE) #not an alpha-numeric type column i.e its a numeric type
    {
      for(j in 1:length(varColData))
      {
        if(!is.na(varColData[j]))
        {
          varCellData<-varColData[j]

           if(grepl("Max.",varCellData)==TRUE)
             varCellData<-gsub("Max.","",varCellData,fixed = TRUE)
           if(grepl("Min",varCellData)==TRUE)
             varCellData<-gsub("Min.","",varCellData,fixed = TRUE)
           if(grepl("Median",varCellData)==TRUE)
             varCellData<-gsub("Median","",varCellData,fixed = TRUE)
           if(grepl("Mean",varCellData)==TRUE)
             varCellData<-gsub("Mean","",varCellData,fixed = TRUE)
           if(grepl("1st Qu.",varCellData)==TRUE)
             varCellData<-gsub("1st Qu.","",varCellData,fixed = TRUE)
           if(grepl("3rd Qu.",varCellData)==TRUE)
             varCellData<-gsub("3rd Qu.","",varCellData,fixed = TRUE)
           if(grepl(":",varCellData)==TRUE)
             varCellData<-gsub(":","",varCellData,fixed = TRUE)

           varColData[j]<-varCellData
        }
      }
    }
    else if(grepl("Alpha-Numeric",sug_dtype[i],fixed = TRUE) ==TRUE) #alpha-numeric type column
    {
      sum_dframe[,i]<-NULL #blank the cell
    }
  }
```

But I am unable to edit the cell values - seems like R doesn't allow me to change the values of the "Factor" once its generated.

The error thrown is :

**Warning in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, j, value = "   :1  ") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated**

How to make this editable ?

Comment: `str(summary(my.vector))` and you can see that summary simply returns a named vector, you can access them using `[]`

Comment: Not part of your question but you could use `|` in gsub to put all the conditions together. Something like this (but watch out for characters you may need to escape): `gsub("Max|Min|.........","",varCellData)`